# Need current user in init method odoo

Tags: report, odoo

I am creating a view report in odoo8(old api) using init method. I need current user(logged in) in init(). Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is an example:

```
def init(self, cr):
    tools.drop_view_if_exists(cr, 'xyz')
    if user.some_field == '':
        query = """Query1"""
    else:
        query = """Query2"""
    cr.execute(query)
```

I need to access one of the field from current logged in user.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: Added example for your reference

Comment: You can check `account/report/account_report.py` at `def _init(self, cr, uid):`.

Comment: return self._init(cr, 1) -  they have used id 1(superuser) while calling _init where as  need current logged in user